# Disable Joomla 1.5 Session Cookie for guests

Tags: session, cookies, joomla, joomla1.5

Does anyone know how to disable all cookies for guest visitors in Joomla 1.5?

Its the session cookie for user tracking etc. An example cookie name is 42fc2fcbe1f5d7c02b9f97a0e48bbbe2

There is a fix here [Joomla 1.0 Fix](http://docs.joomla.org/Disable_all_cookies_for_normal_visitors_in_Joomla), but its for Joomla 1.0.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix here http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=621362#p2509548

It is stated to be for Joomla 1.5.23. I haven't tested it, but it does appear to be similar to the one you link to.